# Invariance of angular momentum states to 180 degree rotations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

Can it be shown that an angular momentum eigenstate $ | j, 0 \rangle $ with even $j$ is invariant to 180 degree rotations about the y axis (or any axis $\bot$ z)?

I was able to do this using properties of the Wigner D matrices but it seemed excessively complicated and lacking in physical insight. Intuition is telling me that the invariance is a consequence of the invariance of *any* state to the composition of two identitical 180 degree rotations and the fact that $ | j, 0 \rangle $ for even j is a "square" in the sense that
$$
| j=2k, 0 \rangle = \sum_{m=-k}^k c(k, m; k, -m | j 0 ) | m, k \rangle \otimes | k, -m \rangle
$$

Is my intuition accurate?

Comment: I think you can use the fact that $J_z$ transforms as a vector under rotations and act with both sides of $ J_z R_{y}(\pi) = R_{y}(\pi) \left( R_{y}(-\pi) J_z R_{y}(\pi) \right) = - R_{y}(\pi) J_z$ on your state. That will let you find that your rotated state is still an eigenstate of $J_z$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Yes but what about the phase factor and its dependence on $j$?

Comment: It seems like you can use the results from here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) to find the phase, and in this case we would be interested in $d^{j}_{0 \, 0} (\pi)$ with $j$ an integer, which seems to produce $(-1)^j$.